# Sound quality problem on Dell Vostro 14 3000

Tags: sound, dell

We have purchased this brand new Dell Vostro 14 3000 laptop which comes with 8GB RAM and SSD drives.

Tried installing latest Ubutnu 20.04.3 LTS on this machine, but it has problem with the sound quality. When any kind of sound is played there is a weird buzz in the back ground.

Have tried searching for any updated drives on Dell website, but could not find any.

Is anyone else facing similar problem ? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Regards,
Sam

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 may be too old to support your brand new Dell. Boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 DVD/USB and see if the sound is better. If not, you may have to edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

Comment: This ^^^ and keep in mind even brand new computers need firmware updates.